# Convert file one word per line

Tags: vim, scripting, sed, awk, vi

I would like to convert a text file containing words, space separate to a file where each word appears on a separate line

```
 sdf sdfsd= sdfsdf 
sdfsdf
```

will become

```
  sdf
  sdfsd= 
  sdfsdf 
  sdfsdf
```

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
:%s/\s\+/\r/g
```

Explained:

```
:%     // whole file
 s     // substitute
 \s\+  // some number of whitespace characters
 \r    // for carriage return
```

Thanks to @[Dummy00001](https://stackoverflow.com/users/360695/dummy00001) for the `+` idea.

Answer (score 1):

enter the following command:

:%s/ /\r/g

or whatever the carriage return is for your environment.  \r for *nix, \n for windows.

Comment: '\r' is the right answer: when matching, end of line is '\n', when substituting end of line is '\r'. Regardless of the platform. VIM would handle the rest automatically. Only enhancement I would suggest is adding `\+` after space: `:%s/ \+/\r/g`

Comment: @Dummy rad, didn't know that \r and \n were platform independent.  Thanks!

Comment: I often use `<C-V><C-M>` to type a newline, which then appears as `^%`.

Answer (score 1):

This is also easy to write as a shell script, you don't need `sed` or `awk`:

```
bash$ for word in $(cat input.txt); do echo "$word" >> output.txt; done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ tr " " "\n"<file|sed -n '/^$/!p'
sdf
sdfsd=
sdfsdf
sdfsdf
```